# Generate Private Key from Pem String Golang

Tags: go, cryptography, rsa, private-key, pem

I am trying to generate private and public key objects in Golang from PEM strings heres my example

```
    r := strings.NewReader(privateKey)
    pemBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    block, _ := pem.Decode(pemBytes)
    if block == nil {
        log.Println(block)
    }
```

Heres my PEM string

```
 var privk = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----"+
"MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQDKlvdvjS7EEkYm"+
"RcMYBemMNvIbMRoJPBuwtRHph8pehi/BUXmTUsGUSDelFAl6tH2eMpHD6FpMJkiu"+
"PAm875yJYo9nxgnH8SNzS1FSR05qoFkJGSvkQwLd++V4Z17kqg9LyzQf/XGSiGGm"+
"VbvPS8rkJUdrFxgTjqhw8KIfNXGG4zLNcB6i0YgW2lZFgaFB16J3/O4KDm21bgdi"+
"qI6F5xKel/YSQl+AfF2NlFt5xI3wuZ4YhD7wrp3WWgiS/JIxu0ESDmJTYExdb3K0"+
"Dh6bmQl+wYJbkBpO2csNRDehtM2YEU83N8mmlSbIbSSinZYT3KwT9JQbd8QqJZCP"+
"/mOPFacrAgMBAAECggEAMqGWR3fWd0RF6ezHfGqF2vgke+1Cn4o5NWmbh2zbg9Iv"+
"fzYYl1w4axG9bnFaiSMwvefPjFG2t49d3MW+fUy5J5DNXFcfPKwkev0Y3uJZU8at"+
"WdvDn3Gr9sSsrfHPwoBKAFxRs6kIyGFzXjnRDVbY5zn15mrIJqMhr9BEBF6798TA"+
"qTG0FYTqkGK0D+FVfaWXvQ0u9Jw0KootS4kKHNwDmbZK2xYI2Ilt1ikeN9MMt8ZD"+
"tXV4shTnQaYPty5Atr9Dzh052FTnlwsclVo33XHF2N2dfe7TaJYTaf5uXuh7Vkj3"+
"99bKuvA8iLmEVe+i86L9K9LD5QEywO/sNcqQkNU8sQKBgQDkycMSv1dfSAgSZywU"+
"hcJqFWJ3TpAP5aoWqw8Svill3Qs6/2zatU4XC4tzRX9KW437M4ORNee/XrCi9z4L"+
"VOeOtR+gp/zn9DebBzaEdTfMlof+znPfx9fVIpBkpjezDgiFNkeeMnKTQrT/kULl"+
"Zso29pCfgO/57L9Vi3pjiqKt0wKBgQDir4EDVesZTGcBstSRLIGrUQFmvxICPaMm"+
"0PogvQhUv8UFMxx6nBl/ZB7AZWQH0TRlpVL7iqS2clO1dQOgrtgwgUV4m3Ml9Ivr"+
"vI2fgCWzFudPst3oSu9Udc9Pq995Pl2nnwV612p3P6p3wgCaFjbouyyJZxNmHQj/"+
"JPtv65nSSQKBgQDVcRnJorLLlHLbYF9yYfunZn3vWl7yRcvxy/KLBNewTZENoIAY"+
"Zm8M9ttJVjvTziheg4ep8EVdduSJlOnQPoysyXNROYeril5aBlepKYY+Gu2THV5j"+
"FpjYIZ/eFmf+Zwgx5xrXjq7vjZs4lnd3dvcOYec4t1yqqGE0WKR8uzjbuwKBgAYL"+
"0FEadY7TLtwovOqyWTMMkhD/f6d3pWZfpIxC/nnkM4kT9+p9R2DSds+C5MwglFkx"+
"s6jp5cLIAduRJ2udvj5s9EFnRAb7ItBC0zQx4s+ICNtjVe/gL8n86m6hkvBU7YKP"+
"B0JjhH9xv0Y6cnGprgU/GM0BZs8ObzL+9YXirtOhAoGACk1TGT6I5oMHLDB4yOOe"+
"a7dT+kAY6a2W2Sq2e0VN70EkVmXGC6ODpRzPcH7nojcMN5jk8QHHosWNK8DECwAj"+
"uCGYn8G/0yAlhkddzE1+y1f5nVm+GCQTrdMMuqOwJnosifdoNDbWg4oGiBRt1uwI"+
"aoxbWonlDAZaLC+8Bxe1Hss="+
"-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

The pem.Decode function returns nil everytime what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Needless to say I hope this is a throwaway private key :)

Comment: yes it is @twotwotwo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There needs to be a newline after `"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----"` and before `"-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"`

https://play.golang.org/p/T0jR2uzGp5

Comment: Another trick is to use backticks: https://play.golang.org/p/LifNuyiGUI